# how to store a value of ls | grep test | wc -l in variablels

Tags: linux, shell

```
$a=ls | grep test | wc -l
```

I want to store wc -l count in a variable, I don't shell scripting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On bash like shells (zsh etc.), you can do

```
a=$(ls | grep test | wc -l)
```

You can get the value back using `$a`. (e.g. `echo $a`).

The older syntax was to use backticks like so

```
a=`ls | grep test | wc -l`
```

but this is best avoided. It doesn't nest and has a few other problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just use backtick (`)

```
$ a=`ls | grep test | wc -l`
$ echo $a
1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the below example.

```
a=$(ls | grep test | wc -l)

echo $a
```

Lemme know if it works.